# Unknown connections listed

Tags: 14.04, networking, network-manager

I have two connections in the network manager named respectively "ASUS_Z00AD Network" and "Nokia 113 Network", both listed as `Disconnected`. They seem to be some kind of wired connection, but I don't know neither of them. 
I mean, I surely have an Asus phone which I sometimes connect to the laptop in order to charge it, but I don't have any Nokia.

I've tried many times to delete the corresponding files from the `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` directory, but they continue to reappear without any specific reason.

What are these connections? Is there a way to know which process created these files? Can they pose a security risk even if they appear as disconnected?

Comment: Are you sure that they are actually connected and configured, or are they just "in range"?  Are you plugging in phone devices to your USB ports? (USB tetherable devices show like this - my iPhone iPad and Galaxy Tab E tablet all show like this when plugged into the computer)

Comment: @ThomasWard Well, sometimes I connect my phone via usb to charge it, and sometimes I use it as Hotspot to access the web. So, maybe (??!?) I can justify the ASUS network, but what about the Nokia 113? I don't have any smartphone of this brand. Also, if I delete them, after a few second or minutes they reappear and I'm pretty sure that no one connected a device to my laptop in the meantime.

Comment: Ok, problem found. It seems to be related to old bluetooth connections where the "Use your mobile phone as a Network device" flag was checked. Thanks for the time @ThomasWard

Answer (score 1):

Ok, problem solved.

The problem is related to old Bluetooth devices paired with my laptop. For some of these devices, I checked the "Use your mobile phone as a Network device" flag. Unchecking them or simply removing the paired device did the trick.